# Pandas left join were NA values on right table are taken as a wildcard

Tags: python, pandas, merge, out-of-memory, na

Does anyone know a efficient way of joining 2 dataframes on multiple columns taking NA values as wildcards?

**Example of my use case:**

I have a dataframe `df_a` like this:

```
stop1   stop2   stop3   stop4   stop5   stop6   stop7
ES       IT      GB      DE      AT      US      CA
ES       IT      DE      CH
```

And a dataframe `df_p` with actions patterns like this (sequence of stops and actions that may or may not contain NA values):

```
stop1   act1    stop2   act2    stop3   act3    stop4     act4
ES      sell     IT                             
ES      sell     IT     sell                      DE      buy
DE      buy      CH
```

I would like to left join `df_a` and `df_p` and assign the pattern with column matches, taking null values as a comodin

In this case, the expected output should be:

```
stop1   act1   stop2    act2   stop3    act3   stop4    act4    stop5   act5    stop6   act6   stop7
ES      sell    IT      sell    GB               DE      buy     AT              US             CA
ES      sell    IT              DE      buy      CH
```

The first row matches pattern in rows 1 and 2 but row 2 matches more rows so we assign that one. The second row in matches at the start of the route pattern 1 and at the end of the route pattern 3 so we assign both.

I am working with a lot of data so i need an efficient way for doing this. Also, what do you think is better doing an iteration row by row or using pd.merge?

Thanks in advance,

Alberto

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. Why does row 2, col 'act3' have 'buy' in it? That value doesn't appear in the 'act3' col of the input datasets.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for checking. Is because ```df_p``` contains relative positions so i need to join it at every step.
In this case:

 ```df_a.merge(df_p, how= 'left', left_on = ['stop3', 'stop4','stop5','stop6','stop7'], right_on =['stop1', 'stop2','stop3','stop4'])```

Comment: Even if you do that, you still won't get 'buy' moving from 'act4' to 'act3'.

Comment: so thats the main question, how to join taking ```na``` values as a wildcard

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using `merge`. It will look for the common columns if you don't specify them:

```
df = df_a.merge(df_p, how='left')
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
print(df)

  stop1 stop2 stop3 stop4 stop5 stop6 stop7 act1 act2 act3 act4
0    ES    IT    GB    DE    AT    US    CA
1    ES    IT    DE    CH
```

Comment: Hi NYC coder, thanks for checking. In this case all columns will be common, what i need is that the join take ```na``` values as a wildcard (I added a table with the desired output at the end of the question)